# SQL DB Design for product builder

Tags: sql, database-design

We're adding functionality to allow product building.

For example, user can configure different attributes which can either be a plain value (height, color etc) or an existing product (there can be a choice of knobs for a piece of furniture).

I'm now constructing the DB design, and I'm looking for suggestions. What I came up with is the following.

**Products** - existing products table *Ex: ProductA*

**ParentProducts** - idParentProduct *Ex: ProductB*

**ParentProduct_Attributes** - idParentProduct, idAttribute, Type (Product/Value) *Ex: Height, Knob*

**ParentProduct_Attribute_Values** - idAttribute, idValue, Value *Ex: 10"*

**ParentProduct_Attribute_ChildProducts** - idAttribute, idChildProduct, Type (Reg. Product / Child Product) *Ex: ChildProductA, ProductA*

**ChildProducts** - idChildProduct

This just seems like a lot of steps to get the actual attribute value.

For example, I have a piece of furniture, ProductB. ProductB has height and Knob. The choices for height are 10", 12" (values), and the choices for knobs are ChildProductA, ProductA (Products) - each coming from different tables. ChildProductA is a childproduct, while ProductA is a regular product, so again, two separate tables.

Any input on this? Different ideas?

Hope I was clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a definite hierarchy 'depth' in place for each product?  In other words, does each Child belong to one Parent, or can a Child product have other Children?

Comment: Let's assume just one level down for now - a product can't have grand-children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following structure:

```
Products - idProduct, type (Regular / Parent / Child)
Product_Attributes - idAttribute, idProduct
Product_Attributes_Values - idValue, idAttribute, value, idProduct
```

This way you are left with only 3 tables. The `Product_Attributes_Values` table has the fields `value` and `idProduct` which are both `NULL`-able. If `value` is set, then it is a simple value. If `idProduct` is set, then it's a product and it should be a foreign key for `Products`.

The type differentiation between Regular, Parent and Child products is made through the `type` field in `Products`. If needed, you can make additional checks and/or validation in your application, outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParentProduct_Attributes - idParentProduct, idAttribute, Type (Product/Value) Ex: Height, Knob

ParentProduct_Attribute_Values - idAttribute, idValue, Value Ex: 10"
```

instead of creating a separate table for values(ParentProduct_Attribute_Values ) it should be in one table. Denormalization help to fasten queries in some condition. since one join will be reduces for every query Select values table .